# Formula to determine the number of possible dice combination to reach certain value

Tags: combinatorics

I am having a headache to this simple problem.

The goal is to find the number of total combination to reach the target value.

For example:

```
target = 5
number of combination is 7

5
4, 1
3, 2
3, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
2, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: thank you for that sir, i have no idea what i'm looking for or trying to achieve

Answer (score -1):

This helped me for the logic:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

I am a programmer and I needed a function to determine the partition

```
function partition(goal, maxNumber){

    if (maxNumber==0)
        return 0;
    if (goal==0)
        return 1;
    if (goal<0)
        return 0;

    return partition(goal,maxNumber-1) 
    + partition(goal-maxNumber,maxNumber);
}

var goal = 700;
var maxNumber = 6; //because dice

document.write(partition(goal,maxNumber));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/816706)

Comment: im sorry my bad